# drawrectangle display only half of it

Tags: picturebox, drawrectangle

I have this code to draw a rectangle on a 256z256 picturebox, however, I don't see the whole rectangle, I only see half of it.. what it might be?

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen,0,0,256,256);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it draws it from the center? Try

```
Rectangle m_rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 512, 512);    
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen,m_rectangle);
```

Just a stab in the dark.

Comment: That didn't work, it draws the rectangle from the center

Comment: it worked with DrawRectangle(mypen,0,0,255,255); so it may be something related to the edges of my picturebox and the container. Thanks anyways!